# So I have a triangle with the point (100, 90) the distance (11) and the angle of the line (45º) Can I find the other point of the line? How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, trigonometry

okay so I am trying to draw a triangle, the triangle can be completely random, on a canvas in JavaScript

so I got the angles and the side for triangle ABC(this is not what I'm calling it in the code)

the sides

```
AB(11)
AC(12)
BC(13)
```

the angles which are solved in a function

```
BAC(69)
ABC(52)
BCA(59)
```

And the starting Point of the triangle at (100, 90)

The question I am having is how do I find the other points to the Triangle
I thought the easiest way to draw it would be to draw a line that goes to each point

So I tired the mathematics with this code (I found on another page but )

```
function FindTriPoints(){
//Y2 = H(Sin(A)) + Y1
//X2 = Sqrt((H^2)-(Y2^2)) + X1
pointX1 = 100;
pointY1 = 90;

pointY2 = s3 * (Math.sin(angle1*Math.PI/180)) + pointY1;
pointX2 = Math.sqrt((s3 * s3) - (pointY2 * pointY2)) + pointX1;

alert("X2 = " + pointX2 + "\n Y2 = " + pointY2)
}
```

but X2 ends up becoming NaN because it is a negative value that it is trying to square root.

Edit Thanks to Cbroe and Jing3142 for helping me with Y2

Comment: `Math.sin` takes its argument in radian, not in degree.

Comment: So I should have a variable keep the radian value in my other function and call that? or should I do this (Math.sin(angle1) * 180 / Math.PI)?

Comment: If angle in degrees use Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180)

Comment: If the triangle is completely random why not choose three random points, no need for any trigonometry then.

Comment: @jing3142 Because it has randomized sides not points. and I would still have to use the distance formula to find the sides so I can output that on the console.

Comment: @K4b6 If you are truly getting a random triangle by randomizing sides then not all random sets of three numbers will give you a triangle and for the ones that do you will have to use the cosine and sine rules to find the angles, choose a random start for a random vertex and a random orientation for the triangle then this seems complicated. For me choosing three random points ensuring they do not all lie on a straight line and then doing distance (and angle calculations if wanted) seems more straight forward.

Comment: This is a trivial problem if you understand how vectors work: x = x0 + r*cos(theta), y = y0 + r*sin(theta), where (x0, y0) = (100, 90) is the starting point, r = 11 is the distance, and the angle theta = 45 degrees = =pi/4 radians.

Comment: @jing3142 Well I can agree with that but when I started the project it wasn't to draw the triangle. I made a bet with someone that I would make a program that checked the length of the sides to see if the object was a true triangle it kindof snowballed from there, and that was two weeks ago, I don't want to change that portion of the code now :P (AB + BC > AC)

Comment: @duffymo as you can tell I have no Idea how vectors work :/ So thank you for the help but what if the angle is random pi/4 doesn't work there would this be better or worse to do?

cos-1 A = (b2 + c2 - a2)/2bc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well if you know valid triangle sides lengths (l1,l2,l3) and their angles (a,b,c) ...

- then it is quite simple with vector math ...

[image: triangle]

```
// compute directions
a1=0;
a2=180-b;
a3=a2+180-c;
a3=-b-c;
a3=-a;
// convert them from [deg] to [rad]
a1*=Math.pi/180.0;
a2*=Math.pi/180.0;
a3*=Math.pi/180.0;
// compute points
A=(x0,y0); // your start point is known
B=A+l1*dir(a0)=(x0+l1*Math.cos(a0),y0+l1*Math.sin(a0));
B=A+l1*dir( 0)=(x0+l1               ,y0                 );     // a0 is always zero
C=A-l3*dir(a3)=(x0-l3*Math.cos(a3),y0-l3*Math.sin(a3));    // C from A point
C=B+l2*dir(a2)=(x0+l1+l2*Math.cos(a2),y0+l2*Math.sin(a2)); // C from B point
```

[notes]

- as you can see there are more **alternatives** for some variables **choose one you like**
- do not forget to check if l1+l2>l3 and l1+l3>l2 and l2+l3>l1
- if not then your lengths are not valid triangle sides
- also a+b+c = 180
- if not then your angle computation is wrong
- if you want to **over-check the triangle** then compute **C** from **A** and from **B** point
- if they are not the same (their distance > some accuracy constant like 0.001)
- then it is not a valid triangle

Comment: Thank you sir, this actually explained a lot of the math to me, I have been getting an error for a while now were the line drawn was a obtuse angle yet it was getting acute. this ended up fixing it.